# Symfony 2/Doctrine - Always available DB Connection?

Tags: php, database, variables, symfony1

Accoring to the Symfony 2 Documentation, you have to use the following PHP code to connect to the database and execute a query...

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$users = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM users');
```

I'm a complete novice with Symfony 2 but I am experienced with OOP. I was wondering if it was possible to have a globally available `$conn` variable that I can access from any bundle. The `$conn` variable would contain the value of `$this->get('database_connection')` so I don't have to retype `$conn = $this->get('database_connection');`it every time I want to make a new query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

global variables are most of the time NOT something you want in OOP. They are confusing when it comes to a method which deals with multiple variables and they might even be hidden by local variables. For me, working with statements like

```
$anything = $this->get('what.the.hell.why.arent.those.identifiers.shorter');
```

is as annoying as for you so I ended up in creating one subclass of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller per project which provides methods which call get with the actual identifiers. In your case I would create a method

```
public function getDatabaseConnection()
{
    return $this->get('database_connection');
}
```

In general - why don't you use Doctrine for managing the DB connection? Most of the queries can be done by the ORM and this is the way to work with a real object-oriented interface to the database. Think about it, I'm also playing with Symfony2/Doctrine since some days and it really feels good. In the beginning, it might look like a hell of configuration, but once you've done the basic configs, the development is really fast! :)

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly trial out both methods to see which works best.